# how to add 4 buttons separate or in toolbar using twitter bootstrap or simple css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

I want to add 4 buttons in a toolbar (in the end i.e after PoP input) so that the individual width of the buttons itself get adjusted according to screen size but they still remain in one line i.e. together with the toolbar occupying whole width of page.Also i want to know how to show a particular text when hovered over the button.
Plz help...

```
    <body style="background-size: 100% auto;color: white;font-size: 126%">

    <input type="date" id="date" placeholder="mm/dd/yy">Date</input>
    <input type="number"  placeholder="00">Fs</input>
    <input type="number"  placeholder="00">PoP</input>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use percentage.

See the HTML:

```
<div class="block one"></div>
<div class="block two"></div>
<div class="block three"></div>
<div class="block four"></div>
```

Now, the CSS:

```
.block {
    width: 25%;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
}

.block.one {
    background-color: red;
}

.block.two {
    background-color: green;
}

.block.three {
    background-color: orange;
}

.block.four {
    background-color: magenta;
}
```

To play, [click here to access CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fhvIc).

Comment: @chiefGui Hey...i am sorry to say but this could not serve the purpose as the divs get grouped or ungrouped on changing the screen sizes..help..

Comment: @chiefGui...hey..problem soleved...i inserted two <br/>...alignment working fine now..now the problem remains that the text goes out of the div when size of div decreases...how to handle it..

Comment: I want that the text inside the button should not go out of the div used for button when size of screen decreases....i used the code of this link.. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fhvIc